# Bluetooth Core Framework callback routine peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers: isn't called

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, xcode5

I'm trying to figure out how to make certain callbacks trigger.
On the peripheral `peripheralManager:central:didSubscribeToCharacteristic:` is called correctly and it sends a chunk (first of two) of data to the central which receives it in `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` as expected.

Now there's one chunk left which is supposed to be sent in the peripheral's callback `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:` according to [Apple's test application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html).

I've tested and verified and it works fine there. It's a bit fishy though as according to the docs it's only supposed to be called when the peripheral manager's `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:` fails.

*How do I make the peripheral send the remaining chunk?* I can supply you with code, but it's almost identical (I'm using an array of NSData chunks instead of one large NSData like the example) to the example application I linked to, I'm more curious as to how the callback chain works and what needs to be in place for the different selectors to trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to trigger `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:` by using a loop in `sendData` (which is called from `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:` and `peripheralManager:central:didSubscribeToCharacteristic:`).

```
- (void)sendData {
    BOOL success = YES;
    while (success && ([_outgoingDataQueue count] > 0)) {
        NSData *chunk = [_outgoingDataQueue peek];
        success = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:chunk
                                    forCharacteristic:self.characteristic
                                 onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
        if (success) {
            [_outgoingDataQueue dequeue];
        }
    }
}
```

This does not feel like the correct way to send data as chunks to the central.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is the normal way of operation. The peripheral manager handles the data sending and implements flow control according to the current settings. E.g. if you are using indications instead of notifications, then each update has to be acknowledged by the receiver before you can send again.

Notifications on the other hand are similar to UDP packets. They can get lost. To make sure that the data arrived error free, you need to implement additional control flow management.

All in all, you are doing it right.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to soak in that I need to return every time it doesn't send a chunk for the callback to trigger.

Comment: @MdaG Yes, this is not very well articulated in the documentation, and the example app itself shows very bad practice actually. (Conglomerating all functionality in a single function.) I just thought it will be good for you to get some feedback that you are doing it more or less right.

Comment: So, in a nontrivial example with multiple characteristics, one would have to maintain a collection of queues, one for each characteristic? Or maybe a queue that contains dictionaries that tie the data to the characteristic?